# Multiple columns in text block

Tags: numbering, multicol, line-numbering

I'd like to have a text with two columns and line-numbering every 5th line, starting new page each. Is there a command or package for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

```
%              V-------V - Two colum
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\setlength{\columnsep}{1cm}% Space between two columns

%           V------V - Reset each page
\usepackage[pagewise]{lineno}% https://ctan.org/pkg/lineno?lang=en

\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for dummy text

\begin{document}

\modulolinenumbers[5]% each 5th line

\linenumbers% Turn line numbering on

\lipsum[1-20]% Dummy text

\end{document}
```